# how can I convert text to tag upon pressing enter inside textfield @mui in react

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, textfield

[image]

As you can see in the picture, when a user types something, a dropdown opens up with given options(predefined array). Upon selecting any of the options, it converts the selected option a  tag.

I want to achieve the same but I don't want to provide a list. Whatever user types should convert to tag upon pressing enter

Comment: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#multiple-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need this. It is a free solo AutoCompelete without any list options.
I made this [example in codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/limittags-material-demo-forked-dfux29?file=/demo.tsx:0-517) for you.

```
    import * as React from "react";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function LimitTags() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="tags-filled"
      options={[]}
      defaultValue={[top100Films[13].title]}
      freeSolo
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="filled"
          label="freeSolo"
          placeholder="Favorites"
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have not yet implemented this in my application yet, but yeah it is almost what I was looking for